# Selenium testing with AWS Lambda Node.js 12.x - Error saying "Chromedriver not found"

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to run my Selenium tests on AWS Lambda with runtime Node.js 12.x, but I've been running into an error.

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.",
  "trace": [
    "Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.",
    "    at new ServiceBuilder (/var/task/aws-Lambda-Selenium-2.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:232:13)",
    "    at getDefaultService (/var/task/aws-Lambda-Selenium-2.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:321:22)",
    "    at Function.createSession (/var/task/aws-Lambda-Selenium-2.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:695:44)",
    "    at createDriver (/var/task/aws-Lambda-Selenium-2.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:155:33)",
    "    at Builder.build (/var/task/aws-Lambda-Selenium-2.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:662:16)",
    "    at Runtime.module.exports.testFn [as handler] (/var/task/aws-Lambda-Selenium-2.0/handler.js:35:32)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

**I know that a similar question has been answered recently, but I've used the `chrome-aws-lambda` npm package and this still hasn't worked.** My Lambda function has 2GB of memory at its disposal, and I've limited the time outs to 5 min. Below I have placed the code of my `handler.js`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
'use strict';

module.exports.testFn = async (event, context, callback) =>
{
    const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
    const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
    const builder = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome');
    const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
    const defaultChromeFlags = 
    [
        '--headless',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--window-size=1280x1696',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data',
        '--hide-scrollbars',
        '--enable-logging',
        '--log-level=0',
        '--v=99',
        '--single-process',
        '--data-path=/tmp/data-path',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--homedir=/tmp',
        '--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir'
    ];

    const HEADLESS_CHROME_PATH = '/var/task/aws-Lambda-Selenium-2.0/node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium.br';

    chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath(HEADLESS_CHROME_PATH);
    chromeOptions.addArguments(defaultChromeFlags);

    builder.setChromeOptions(chromeOptions);

    let driver = await builder.build(); // <-- program is not getting passed this line

    await driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    await driver.getTitle().then(() =>
    {
        console.log("Page title for " + "https://www.google.com/" + " is ");
    });

    await driver.quit();
}
```